# Regex to replace new line and spaces into space

Tags: regex, pspad

I have a string like that

```
-U, --update                     Update this program to latest version. Make
                                 sure that you have sufficient permissions
                                 (run with sudo if needed)
-i, --ignore-errors              Continue on download errors, for example to
                                 skip unavailable videos in a playlist
--abort-on-error                 Abort downloading of further videos (in the
                                 playlist or the command line) if an error
                                 occurs
```

My goal is to convert it into this:

```
-U, --update                     Update this program to latest version. Make sure that you have sufficient permissions (run with sudo if needed)
-i, --ignore-errors              Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist
--abort-on-error                 Abort downloading of further videos (in the playlist or the command line) if an error occurs
```

using regex.

I assumed

```
-U, --update                     Update this program to latest version. Make
                                 sure
```

is the same as `-U, --update                     Update this program to latest version. Make` + new line + certain number of spaces. So to replace this, I need new line `\n` + (    ) to be replaced with space.

Yet it doesn't replace it.

What is the right regex(I am using pspad for it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the nuances of pspad, but the following find and replace seems to work:

```
Find: \n[ ]+
Replace: (nothing)
```

### Demo

Note the above pattern would only match newlines at the end of lines which are followed by a continuation line, which is padded at the start by one or more spaces.  The pattern would *not* match the final line in an given explanation.